# Jest Mocking promise not working with error Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, promise, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to implement a test for my ExpressJS app. I could not find any solution after googling, please help and save my day...!

Error I am getting.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

       6 |   const arg1 = req.query.arg1;
       7 |   const arg2 = req.query.arg2;
    >  8 |   model.getExceptions(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

The test files are given below

```
_test_/file.test.js:

import { getExceptions }  from '../file';
jest.mock('../model');

describe('file.js', () => {
  test('testing file...', () => {
    const req = {query: {arg1: 'SOME'}};
    const resp = {};
    expect(getExceptions(req, 'dd', resp)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(getExceptions(req, 'ssd', resp)).toBe({test: 10});
  });
})
```

Mock file:

```
_mocks_/model.js

const model = {
  getExceptions: (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    process.nextTick(
      () =>
        arg1
          ? resolve({test: 110})
          : reject({
            error: 'not found.',
          })
    );
  })
}};

export default model;
```

CODE FILES to be tested:

file.js

```
export const getExceptions = (req, res, next) => {
  const arg1 = req.query.arg1;
  const arg2 = req.query.arg2;
  model.getExceptions(arg1, arg2, req.arg3)
  .then(([rows]) => res.write(rows))
  .catch(next);
};
```

model.js

```
const model = {
  getExceptions: (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
    try {
      return db.runQuery(qryName, [arg1, arg2, arg3]); // Custom function
    } catch (e) {
      throw new GatewayTimeoutError(e.message);
    }
  }
};

export default model;
```

Please let me know if any more details required. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.
I am keeping this question in case anyone has similar issues and looking for a solution.

This is very simple mistake - mock folder should be with double dashes.

Correct One:

```
__mocks__
```

Incorrect one:

```
_mocks_
```